# TF-IDF function

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks, tf-idf

I need to implement a tf-idf function in spypark's (Databricks) python.
I have a [csv file](https://filebin.net/8d0fkupze5358dde) (named 'somefile'), and I need the tf-idf of the every word in in the column 'text' (so there should be a cleaning of text first, and also not having duplicates by mistake..)

it should be like this:
1.function the calculates the tf
2.function that calculttes the idf
3. external function that returns the tf-idf of every word (using the above of course)

Comment: Just to help you out, you should probably start with what code you've tried youself and where you've had problems. Otherwise, it looks like you're just wanting us to code for you and that's not really what SO is for.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's going to be as evolved as things in the Scikit world, but it does seem like there is some kind of offering.  Check out the link below and see if it gives you what you want.

https://databricks-prod-cloudfront.cloud.databricks.com/public/4027ec902e239c93eaaa8714f173bcfc/6052175677058526/3537626382528910/5364082293869370/latest.html

It's a bit hard to understand what you really want...